# R tcltk horizontal row of buttons

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit

This code will produce a vertical list of buttons. How do I create a horizontal list of buttons each having a different `command` function?

```
f.frame <- tkframe (w.top)

for(i in 1:10)
    tkpack (tkbutton (f.frame));

tkgrid (f.frame, pady=15);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know r, but the pack command accepts options, such as `side`. For a horizontal row you would pack everything on the left or right side. The default is "top", which yields a vertical stack.

Try this:

```
tkpack (tkbutton (f.frame), side="left")
```